# Will the span of vectors {(1,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0)} form a subspace/basis in the set of fields of dimension 5?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

I have checked a calculator website which checks if a set of vectors is a basis and the one that I put in the title is not. (http://www.mathforyou.net/en/online/vectors/basis/)

By the subspace definition, the vector 0 is contained into the span, 0*(1,0,0,0,0)+0*(0,1,0,0,0), and we can get any other vector from the span with just the independent vectors (1,0,0,0,0) and (0,1,0,0,0) and this span must be a subspace and basis too.

Please tell me if I m doing anything wrong or I misunderstand any concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The span of those vectors is indeed a subspace of dimension $2$ of $\mathbb R^5$, whose dimension is $5$. So, those two vectors do *not* form a basis of $\mathbb R^5$. That's all.

Comment: @Santos Yes they do not form a basis of $\mathbb R^5$, but the span is itself a basis. Is that statement right?

Comment: No. It is wrong. The vectors form a basis, but their span is **not** a basis.

Comment: @Santos But the vectors are independent and they span the subspace, why wouldn't they be a basis. Could you please give me the basis of this span then?

Comment: The correct definition of a basis is a set of vectors that span the whole space and it is a maximal set of linearly independent vectors. Your example is a set of linearly independent vectors (not maximal), and it does not span the whole space.

Comment: Oh ok thank you I understand it now!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.